# Estimate the error variance from statsmodels

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels

Python module statsmodels has some methods for Generalised linear model (GLM) as described in https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/glm.html

I am wondering if there any method available to obtain the estimate of `error variance` for the model fit?

Any pointer will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The results instance has a `scale` attribute that is computed by default using pearson residuals for distributions that do not have a fixed scale = 1 like Poisson and Binomial.

If the family is gaussian, then `scale` is an estimate of the residual variance. For non-gaussian families, the variance is not constant and `scale` is the dispersion parameter.